# Probability of drawing $m$ of $A$ in $n$ cards given a deck of $d$ cards contain $a$ copies of $A$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

As in the title I'm trying to work out what the chances of drawing $m$ copies of a specific card in $n$ draws are given a deck size of $d$ containing $a$ copies of $A$.

I've tried using permutations for this but must be doing something wrong as the solution i get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{n!(d-n)!}{m!(n-m)!d!}
\end{equation}
doesn't even contain $a$, so I must be doing something stupid. Please help a combinatorics noob :(.

Comment: So you want to draw `m` cards out of `a` total and `n-m` cards out of the remaining `d-a` cards?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is drawing w/o replacement (hypergeometric),

$Pr = \frac{\dbinom{a}{m}\dbinom{n-m}{d-a}}{\dbinom {d}{n}}$

Comment: Any chance you could talk me through that?

Comment: I have corrected a typo. The deck has $a$ cards of type A and $d-a$ of type B (say). We draw a total of $n$ cards, of which $m$ are of type A, and the remaining $n-m cards from type B.